# Is $x^2 \sin (x)$ periodic function?

Tags: functions

Is $x^2 \sin (x)$ periodic or not? If yes why and if not why?

I think it should be periodic but it's amplitude would be varying. But still periodic ... I think I'm not sure.

Comment: $x^2\sin x$ is not periodic in the same sense as $\sin x$ is periodic.

Answer (score 3):

For a function to be periodic there must exist a constant $\tau$ such that $f(x+\tau)=f(x)$ for all $x$. The smallest such $\tau$ is the fundamental period (or just the period as opposed to a period)

From what you say you should conclude that your function is not periodic (as you observe the amplitude is changing), what it is is oscillatory, but not periodic.

Answer (score 3):

$x^{2}\sin x$ is not a periodic function. A periodic function satisfies:

$$f(x+P) = f(x) \quad \forall x$$

where P is a constant which denotes the period. Your function does not satisfy this requirement.